# getting the temperature of environment in an android program

Tags: android, android-sensors, temperature

My phone in Huawei g600 and I don't get the temperature sensor in the list of all sensors in my program, but I need the temperature of environment in my application, Does any one has a solution?

```
 List<Sensor> list = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
for(Sensor sensor : list){
   data.append(sensor.getName() + "\n");

 }
sensorslist.setText(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all (in fact almost none) devices have an external temperature sensor.  Its rare hardware and even was discouraged by Google for a while.  The reason is that phones run hot-  the battery can easily get hot enough to burn.  That means any thermometer will be inaccurate.  You're better off with either local weather date via web service, or using a usb or bluetooth device connected to your phone to take temperature.  Even if you find a device with a temperature sensor you can't trust its accuracy, for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Additionally, looking at http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-phones/tech-specs/u8950-en.htm and  http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_g600-4963.php under sensors there is no thermometer mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate it's an old question but I looked into this too. There is a way you can get a good approximation of the outside temperature, from your battery temperature.

In general the formula:

Te = (m *Tc) + k

works.

- Te (external temperature)
- m  (local modifier)
- Tc (Battery temperature)
- k  (-60.522)

For London, for example, m is 2.55 and is dependant on the time of year (summer Vs winter).

[Reference material](http://opensignal.com/reports/battery-temperature-weather/)

[Reference Data (20Mb zip)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/osmwww/reports/battery-temperature-weather/battmap_uk.zip)